# Unable to perform rails generate because of 'unknown database' error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2

This is the error i am getting after doing $ rails generate inside a newly created application using rails new simple_cms -d mysql

```
Users/localuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Unknown database 'simple_cms_development' (Mysql2::Error)
```

Comment: Create the database `simple_cms_development`?

Answer (score 6):

Check that your config/database.yml is correct, and if it is, make sure to

```
rake db:create
```

so that the database gets created

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to connect to a database named simple_cms_development, and it's failing. Is your database.yml correct?